# Find a specific sentence with a given word in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find a sentence with a give word `string1` in the following passage:
Note that

```
HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{B:0,C:5,D:-1,E:false,F:Failure},suffix:_A}DC0DHEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{BC:true,DE:2,FG:0,HI:0,JK:0,string1:Error},suffix:_A}D646HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{Z:{Y:false,X:0,Q:1},suffix:}3AA8
```

So the expected result would be:

```
HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{BC:true,DE:2,FG:0,HI:0,JK:0,string1:Error},suffix:_A}D646
```

So far, I have used the regular expression as follows to chop the desired sentence:

```
([^.]*?string1[^.]*)
```

However, the result is not the desired one as the whole sentence cannot be captured but as follows:

```
A:1,json:{BC:true,DE:2,FG:0,HI:0,JK:0,string1:Error},suffix:_A}D646
```

Therefore, I hope is there anyone can help to solve this little issue. Thanks!

Comment: what about `[i for i in s.split('') if 'string1' in i]` if s is your string? I can't paste the unrecognized characer ``

Comment: You won't be able to split with an empty separator but you can split your string using a regex. `regex.compile('(?=HEAD)').split(s)` and then use a for loop or list comprehension to get the sentence containing `string1`.

Answer (score 0):

If all sentences begin with HEAD, you can do the following:

```
temp = s.split('HEAD')
res = 'HEAD' + [i for i in temp if 'string1' in i][0]

>>> print(res)
'HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{BC:true,DE:2,FG:0,HI:0,JK:0,string1:Error},suffix:_A}D646'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex, you can match HEAD. Then match any char except then directly followed by HEAD.

Then match `string1` again followed by matching any char except directly followed by `HEAD`

```
HEAD(?:(?!HEAD).)*string1(?:(?!HEAD).)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeSl7O/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PfTNmt)

```
import re

pattern = r"HEAD(?:(?!HEAD).)*string1(?:(?!HEAD).)*"
s = ("HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{B:0,C:5,D:-1,E:false,F:Failure},suffix:_A}DC0DHEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{BC:true,DE:2,FG:0,HI:0,JK:0,string1:Error},suffix:_A}D646HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{Z:{Y:false,X:0,Q:1},suffix:}3AA8\n")
matches = re.findall(pattern, s)

print(matches)
```

Output

```
['HEAD,Content,11005,{A:1,json:{BC:true,DE:2,FG:0,HI:0,JK:0,string1:Error},suffix:_A}D646']
```